# React Native Virtual Keyboard blocking input element using KeyboardAwareScrollView

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

My React Native Expo app for iOS has a `Home` screen that displays some chat messages and has a text input element that should stick to the bottom of the device screen, like in most chat apps.

**Github repo**: **[Available here](https://github.com/athenawisdoms/expo-keyboard-aware-problem)**

However, when the virtual keyboard slides up, it hides the `TextInput` element despite having used `KeyboardAwareScrollView`.

[image]

```
import { Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(null);
  const [numNewMessages, setNumNewMessages] = useState(0);

  // Simulate a new message received every few seconds
  setInterval(() => {
    setNumNewMessages((numNewMessages) => numNewMessages + 1);
  }, 3000);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex container h-full">
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView className="flex-grow bg-blue-100">
        {[...Array(10)].map((e, i) => (
          <Text key={i} className="my-10">
            Hello {i}!
          </Text>
        ))}

        {[...Array(numNewMessages)].map((e, i) => (
          <Text key={i} className="my-10">
            New msg {i}!
          </Text>
        ))}
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

      <View className="p-3">
        <TextInput
          className="placeholder:text-slate-400 block bg-white w-full border border-slate-300 rounded-md py-2 px-3 shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 focus:ring-1 sm:text-sm"
          placeholder="Type your message"
          onChangeText={(value) => setInput(value)}
          value={input}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Tried nesting the `TextInput` inside the `KeyboardAwareScrollView`, but this prevents the input element from being stuck to the botttom screen.

How can this problem be fixed while using `KeyboardAwareScrollView` and `SafeViewArea`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, while implementing a chat system, we need to display the newest messages at the bottom and the old ones before that. So, keeping this point in mind, let's say we have an array of messages sorted by `newest to oldest`. Something like this

```js
const messages = [
  {
    id: "1",
    message: "Hello World",
    created_at: "2023-03-22 10:15:00",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    message: "Hello World 2",
    created_at: "2023-03-22 10:14:00",
  },
  .
  .
  .
  and so on
];
```

So, desired way is to display them in inverted form. So, using `FlatList` we can achieve this as follows

```js
<FlatList
  data={[...Array(20)]} // array of messages
  keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
  renderItem={({ _, index }) => (
    <MessageItem
      key={index}
      message="Some Text Message"
    />
  )}
  inverted // This is important
/>
```

So, the point is to Wrap the `Flatlist` and the `TextInput` inside a `KeyboardAvoidingView`, so that when we open tap on the input field, the keyboard smoothly, scrolls the `MainView` and input field focuses.

To, understand the implementation, I have created a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/expo-keyboard-avoiding-problem), you can have a  look how I implemented it. It is working as expected.